# Clickable links in a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

In a dialog describing my change log, I'd like to have some links to our twitter and facebook pages. Because I don't want to have the bare urls in the text, I'm using `Html.fromHtml(..)` and standard html style links (a href). However, I can't get the links to be clickable, regardless of how I do the dialog (via either an AlertDialog.Builder or a Dialog with a custom view). I've also set `linksClickable=true` in the textview, but no luck. If anyone could help me, that'd be great!

change_log_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linlay2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_padding"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/gen_placeholder"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/verticallayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:dividerPadding="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help_close"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/help_close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

current method for calling the dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setTitle(R.string.changetitle);
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.change_log_dialog, null);
((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_view)).setText(getRawAsset(R.raw.change));
dialog.setContentView(v);
return dialog;
```

with getRawAsset(..):

```
public Spanned getRawAsset(int id) {

    InputStream mStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    InputStreamReader mRead = new InputStreamReader(mStream);
    BufferedReader mReader = new BufferedReader(mRead);
    StringBuilder returner = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    try {
        while ((line = mReader.readLine()) != null) {

            returner.append(line);

        }

        return Html.fromHtml(returner.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you would rather use [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) instead of `Html.fromHtml(...)`.  `Linkify`, along with [`Linkify.TransformFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.TransformFilter.html), should be able to convert the links to something more user friendly.

Comment: But that only works with bare urls, doesn't it? I want to have the link on normal text (such as "visit our facebook page"), I don't want the users to see the full urls of our websites because it's a bit ugly